# Объединить два массива

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно объединить два массива вида:

```
    $first_arr = array ('org1', 'org2');
    $second_arr = array ('time1', 'time2');
```

И получить:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => org1
            [1] => time1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => org2
            [1] => time2
        )

)
```

Comment: Ну так напиши код, или хотя бы расскажи что не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прям из [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php#example-4900) пример:

```
$first_arr = ['org1', 'org2'];
$second_arr = ['time1', 'time2'];
$result = array_map(null, $first_arr, $second_arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно - короткий онлайнер. Предполагаю, что далеко не каждый первый слышал про "Выполнение zip операции с массивами" на функции array_map , в реальности хорошо если каждый десятый.

Comment: Ну `array_map` на перебор массивов уже достаточно известная функция, а `null` - это больше хак. Можно туда коллбэк какой-нибудь пихнуть типа `function( ...$el ) { return [ $el ]; }` — будет то же самое